# Get shell environment for use with execle

Tags: c, exec, init.d

I have program that needs to run other programs. It works fine when ran from normal terminal session. When ran with initscript, it doesnt get normal shell environment and most programs fail. So how can i get it to work with initscript?

vixie-cron seems to use execle() and pass envp as argument. But im having hard time to figure out how does it get the shell env settings.

Here is the current code that doesnt work properly with initscript:

```
pid = fork();
if (pid < 0) {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
} else if (pid == 0) {
    execl("/bin/sh", "/bin/sh", "-c", cmd, (char *) NULL);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

EDIT: Something strange happened. Now the same program runs fine even when started by init script. Im sorry, this was kind of useless question. Anyways i got good answers. Thank you for help.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? What's the error? And why aren't you reporting the error in your code? That would seem to be the first thing one does when facing unexpected behaviour...

Comment: The (shell-)enviroment can heavily depend on the user running a process. Did you check this?

Comment: The usual way to get environment variables is to call getenv().  This may be what you do not see.

Comment: Vixie-cron gets the environment variables from built-in variables like `USER` that it automatically sets to the username, and variable assignments that you put in the `crontab` file. You need to decide which variables you need to set, and add them to the environment array that you use in `execle`.

Comment: @jimmcnamara He's not trying to _get_ environment variables, he's trying to _set_ them in the child process.

Comment: Instead of using `execle()` you can use `putenv()` before calling `execl`.

Comment: @Barmar - looks like you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environment variables are passed to and accessed by your program with the optional third `main()` argument. Simply prototype your main function like this :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
```

... to gain access to these variables.

You can then pass it directly to the `exec*e()` family functions.

You can see this documented in the [`execve(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve) man page.